# Is there a way calculate multiple cell values based on multiple criteria in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, filter, sum, google-sheets-formula, match

[image: table example image]

I wish to calculate the total pages based on 2 other criteria, the year and language column.
For example,
how could I calculate the total EN page numbers from 2022?
or the total DE page numbers from 2023?

I have searched on the internet, and found interesting things about google sheet and excel functions: index, match, vlookup ...but i could not find example of what i could use, or maybe i'm just very new at this.
Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=SUM(FILTER(H:H; G:G=2022; I:I="DE"))
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation of what's happening here